# How to avoid specialization for a "big" template class without creating an empty class?

Tags: c++, templates

Given the following :

```
template <typename T0,typename T1,typename T2 , typename T3 , typename T4>
class Tuple
{
private:
    T0 v0;
    T1 v1;
    T2 v2;
    T3 v3;
    T4 v4;

public:
    void f()
    {
        cout << v0 << "," << v1 << "," << v2 << "," << v3 << "," << v4 << endl;
    }

};
```

I want to create a partial class with only two `int`-s , then I must specialize like this:

```
class NullType { };  // create an empty class
template <typename T0, typename T1>
class Tuple<T0,T1,NullType,NullType,NullType >
{
    private:
        T0 v0;
        T1 v1;
    public:
        void func()
        {
            cout << "i'm a specialization" << endl;
        }
};
```

But this implementation would require me to do :

```
Tuple<int,int,NullType,NullType,NullType> b;
```

so that's pretty ugly :)

Is there another way to implement a partial specialization without defining another (empty) class so I can do that : `Tuple<int,int> b1;` ?

Comment: Can you use a C++11-compiler with support for variadic templates? Have you considered using `boost::tuple` (or `std::tuple` if your compiler supports it)?

Comment: @BjörnPollex: I don't mind learning new things :) ... and I'm not using `boost::tuple` , is this supposed to solve that problem ?

Comment: Simplest might be to just typedef it.

Comment: @BjörnPollex: Variadic templates are probably way beyond what is *needed* here. A simple template alias should suffice.

Comment: Late answer and you've got one wlready, I know, but I gathered what you didn't like was having to type the full-spell on the specialization, `tuple<int,int,void,void,void>`, so why not just do `typedef tuple<int,int,void,void,void> your_typename`that_says_what_youre_using this_for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make T2 through T4 default template arguments and use `void` instead of the empty `NullType` class, e.g.:

```
template <typename T0,typename T1,typename T2=void , typename T3=void , typename T4=void> class Tuple { private:
    T0 v0;
    T1 v1;
    T2 v2;
    T3 v3;
    T4 v4;

public:
    void f()
    {
        cout << v0 << "," << v1 << "," << v2 << "," << v3 << "," << v4 << endl;
    }

};

template <typename T0, typename T1> class Tuple<T0,T1,void,void,void > {
    private:
        T0 v0;
        T1 v1;
    public:
        void func()
        {
            cout << "i'm a specialization" << endl;
        } };

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Tuple<int,int> myTuple;
    myTuple.func(); 
    return 0;
}
```

See [here](http://ideone.com/tw0QR) for working example.

EDIT: or, you could just use [boost::tuple](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/tuple/doc/tuple_users_guide.html) or std::tuple with C++11 :)

Comment: If using C++11, [std::tuple](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) is built-in, and probably preferred.

Comment: True, although I am still a bit hesitant to recommend C++11 features because not all compilers support it, which is especially problematic for code that is e.g. open-sourced. You're right though in that it's a built-in option and preferred in a lot of cases, so I updated my answer accordingly

Comment: @Moritz: Nice , but that code is still using the empty class `NullType` ... any other way without it (without C++ 11) ? +1

Comment: @ron: you could use ``void`` instead of ``NullType``, see edit.

Answer (score 2):

If your compiler supports C++11 template aliases that is quite simple to do:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
using tuple2 = tuple<T,U,NullType,NullType,NullType>;
```

Comment: +1 for the elegant and simple solution, although OP wants to avoid "creating an empty class".

Comment: @juanchopanza: This does not create *any* class at all, only an *alias*. I understand from the question that what he wants is to avoid having to create an specialization (or a class that wraps it) and at the same time avoid having to type all the `NullType` in the variable declaration. I might have misunderstood it.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood. I though OP didn't want to declare `class NullType{};`. I didn't mean the template alias was a class!